# Generating a method for linq in NHibernate for avg timespan

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, hql

I'm trying to make avg for timespan work in linq for NHibernate.

I've added registry:

```
public class CustomLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry : DefaultLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry
{
    public CustomLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry()
    {
        this.Merge(new AvgTimeSpanGenerator());
    }
}
```

Generator:

```
public class AvgTimeSpanGenerator : BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod
{
     public AvgTimeSpanGenerator()
    {
        SupportedMethods = new[]
        {
             NHibernate.Linq.ReflectionHelper.GetMethodDefinition<IEnumerable<TimeSpan>>(x => x.Avg())
        };
    }

    public override HqlTreeNode BuildHql(MethodInfo method, Expression targetObject, ReadOnlyCollection<Expression> arguments, HqlTreeBuilder treeBuilder, IHqlExpressionVisitor visitor)
    {
        return treeBuilder.MethodCall("Avg", visitor.Visit(targetObject).AsExpression());
    }
}
```

Please note that my `BuildHql` implementation might be incorrect (haven't really thought it through much), but I placed breakpoint there and it is never hit.

And a method:

```
public static class NHibernateLinqExtension
{
    public static TimeSpan Avg(this IEnumerable<TimeSpan> timeSpan)
    {
        return new TimeSpan((long)timeSpan.Select(x => x.Ticks).Average());
    }
}
```

I've also registered the registry in NHibernate:

```
configuration.LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry<CustomLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry>();
```

But when I execute a query:

```
var data = (from tcdr in uow.UnitOfWorkSession.Query<TCDR>()
                group tcdr.Duration by tcdr.Name into g
                select new
                {
                    MaxDuration = g.Max(),
                    MinDuration = g.Min(),
                    AvgDuration = g.Avg()
                }).ToList();
```

It throws InvalidOperationException `Code supposed to be unreachable`

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregating expression requires a special handling, see [`MergeAggregatingResultsRewriter`](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/5.1.2/src/NHibernate/Linq/ReWriters/MergeAggregatingResultsRewriter.cs#L120). Unfortunately, this class is not injectable with more behavior, and the [rewriter pipeline](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/5.1.2/src/NHibernate/Linq/Visitors/QueryModelVisitor.cs#L30) calls custom rewriters (see [setting `query.query_model_rewriter_factory`](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional)) [too late (line 72)](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/5.1.2/src/NHibernate/Linq/Visitors/QueryModelVisitor.cs#L72), since aggregations needs to be handled before the [group by rewriters (line 39)](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/5.1.2/src/NHibernate/Linq/Visitors/QueryModelVisitor.cs#L39).

All this applies to NHibernate 5.1.2.

It seems to me you are using a version lower than the 5, but your are likely stuck the same.

I do not think you may be able to handle your custom `TimeSpan` average in [linq-to-nhibernate](/questions/tagged/linq-to-nhibernate) without some changes in NHibernate code.

Comment: I wish `linq-to-nhibernate` was more flexible and easy to extend. I've started a new project where I have a lot of complex queries, and almost every query I write I end up rewriting to `HQL` either because it is impossible to write in `LINQ` or the possible approach is not efficient. Thanks for your response though!